# Haiku competition on Meta Stack Overflow might be of interest

Tags: discussion, meta, hats, stackexchange

I just the contributors to Japanese Language might be interested to know of a fun hat-related haiku competition over on Meta Stack Overflow:

> **[Christmas Hat Haiku](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212781)**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: @oldergod: Just a nitpick, "off topic" literally means not within the topic of the site, which is "Japanese". Not being a question doesn't make a post be on some other topic.